# sbt: Add http headers when fetching private maven repo with credentials

Tags: maven, sbt, gitlab, coursier

I try to use [credentials](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials) in my `build.sbt` config in order to retrieve private artifacts from a [gitlab private maven repository](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/packages/maven_repository.md).

But as sbt documentation states :

> The credentials file is a properties file with keys realm, host, user, and password.

And gitab private maven documentation states :

> If a project is private or you want to upload Maven artifacts to GitLab,
>   credentials will need to be provided for authorization. Support is available for personal access tokens and CI job tokens only. Deploy tokens and **regular username/password credentials do not work**.

The only way to authenticate when fetching or pushing artifacts to gitlab maven private repository is to use a maven `settings.xml` file with :

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

I found a workaround to push my private artifacts (intermediate step locally) but I am out of options to use these private artifacts as `libraryDependencies` in other scala repositories.

- Is there anyway to have sbt fetching my private gitlab repository with the required `httpHeaders` ?
- Do you know any workaround (multi-step fetchs) to have my private artifacts retrieved ?

Comment: I'm not sure where the configuration things is coming from ? Based on the [docs of Maven settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) those things do not exist in Maven?

Comment: We can find these settings in [maven wagon doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html)